# Adding html to WooCommerce Store Notice using filters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter

I am trying to add a div wrapper around my WooCommerce Store Notice using a filter.  And I also want to replace the dismiss link with a close icon.

This is what I have so far and it doesn't really work how I want it to;

```
add_filter('woocommerce_demo_store', 'demo_store_filter');

function demo_store_filter($text){
    return str_replace( '<p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store">', '<div class="hello"><p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store"></p></div>', $text);
}
```

Here is the default html for the notice;

```
<p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store">Enter the code <strong>'TLFS5V'</strong> to received £10 off your order when you spend over £100 <a href="#" class="woocommerce-store-notice__dismiss-link">Dismiss</a></p>
```

Here is what I want;

```
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="container"><p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store">Enter the code <strong>'TLFS5V'</strong> to received £10 off your order when you spend over £100 <a href="#" class="woocommerce-store-notice__dismiss-link">(close svg icon here)</a></p></div></div>
```

Is this possible with filters? Or should I do this by creating a new function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it this way :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_demo_store', 'demo_store_filter', 10, 1);

function demo_store_filter($text)
{

    $text = str_replace(array('<p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store">', '</p>', 'Dismiss'), array('<div class="hello"><p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store">', '</p></div>', '(close svg icon here)'), $text);

    return $text;
}
```

**output:**

```
<div class="hello"><p class="woocommerce-store-notice demo_store">as <a href="#" class="woocommerce-store-notice__dismiss-link">(close svg icon here)</a></p></div>
```

tested and working.

Comment: This appears to be broken because there is now a md5 "data-notice-id="12334454546"  - therefore the str_replace is not working any more.