# How to read "Store Notice" values from PHP in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a custom WooCommerce theme and I'm trying to implement a custom site-wide notice banner. I want the user to enable, disable and customize the message via Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Store Notice, just like the Storefront theme, but with custom HTML, CSS and positioning over the page. The idea was to read (somehow) via PHP the "Store Notice" (string) and "Enable Store Notice" (boolean) values and, based on their values, display or not the notice. How can I read those fields via PHP? Thanks.

[image]

**Psuedo:**

```php
...other HTML

<?php if (ENABLE_STORE_NOTICE == true) { ?>

<div class="text-center text-white">
 <span class="heading-xxs letter-spacing-xl">
  <?php echo STORE_NOTICE_MESSAGE; ?>
 </span>
</div>

<?php } ?>

...other HTML
```

Comment: View [`function woocommerce_demo_store()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/d77fc005d2449f4386db6fb330f366f09a5b7e21/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1037-L1058) and [Adding html to WooCommerce Store Notice using filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186414/adding-html-to-woocommerce-store-notice-using-filters/52187195#52187195)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, using the function `is_store_notice_showing()` to get "Enable Store Notice" (boolean) and `get_option('woocommerce_demo_store_notice')` to get "Store Notice" (string) perfectly solved my problem.

**PHP:**

```php
<?php if (is_store_notice_showing()) { ?>
 <div class="text-center text-white">
  <span class="heading-xxs letter-spacing-xl">
   <?php echo get_option('woocommerce_demo_store_notice'); ?>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```